# SQL Server running total to find accounts based upon dollar amount with a 365 day windowing function

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem.  I need to run a daily report to find accounts that have paid $10,000 or more within a 365 period from the date of report run.  I need a query that can take the payment info and do a running total for each account, and should any account have payments made totaling $10,000 or more within the 365 window, the query returns either the date that the threshold is reached or the account number, I can work with either one.

Here is the applicable portion of my query so far, but it is not functioning correctly.  I based it upon another query I have that achieves a similar purpose by subtracting payments from the current balance.  I thought I could modify it to work, but have been unsuccessful.  It is important to note that I have not yet applied the 365 filter.  I am trying to make sure the basic part of the query works first before adding to the complexity.  I am using SQL Server 2014.

```
CREATE TABLE #PaymentDate
(number int,
paymentdate date,
balance money)


;
WITH Balances1 AS
(
    SELECT *,
        SUM(TotalPaid) OVER (PARTITION BY number, DatePaid ORDER BY 
DatePaid, number) AS Balance
    FROM #Accounts
)
, Balances2 AS
(
    SELECT *, ISNULL(LAG(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY number, DatePaid ORDER 
BY DatePaid, number), 0) AS Prev
    FROM Balances1
)
INSERT INTO #PaymentDate
SELECT number, DatePaid, balance
FROM Balances2
WHERE Balance >= 10000 AND Prev < 10000
;
```

It is failing to add correctly or ignoring accounts with a one time payment that meets the criteria.

Some sample data.  The first 3 accounts should all be returned by the query because they have payments totaling 10,000 or more all within the 365 day window (today's date being 8/27/18).  The 4th account should not be included because it takes more than 365 days for the payments to total 10,000 or more:

```
Number  DatePaid    TotalPaid
123456  2017-12-01  12184.46
654321  2018-02-28  10000
231645  2017-05-31  3390
231645  2017-06-29  1565.29
231645  2017-07-26  1565.29
231645  2017-08-28  1565.29
231645  2017-09-28  1565.29
231645  2017-10-27  1565.29
231645  2017-12-01  6783.55
312546  2016-08-01  550
312546  2016-09-06  500
312546  2016-10-04  500
312546  2016-11-07  500
312546  2016-12-06  500
312546  2017-01-04  500
312546  2017-02-08  500
312546  2017-03-07  500
312546  2017-04-10  500
312546  2017-05-09  500
312546  2017-06-07  500
312546  2017-07-05  500
312546  2017-08-07  500
312546  2017-09-05  500
312546  2017-10-11  500
312546  2017-11-09  500
312546  2017-12-11  250
312546  2018-01-16  250
312546  2018-02-20  250
312546  2018-03-20  250
312546  2018-04-23  500
312546  2018-04-23  50
312546  2018-05-29  500
312546  2018-07-03  500
312546  2018-07-31  204
```

Any insight into where I took a wrong turn is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First build the rolling sum for all payments in the period. Then select all of them where the sum was greater than or equal 10000 and add use `row_number()` to get the earliest day.

```
SELECT number,
       datepaid,
       totalpaid
       FROM (SELECT number,
                    datepaid,
                    totalpaid,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY number
                                       ORDER BY datepaid) rn
                    FROM (SELECT number,
                                 datepaid,
                                 sum(totalpaid) OVER (PARTITION BY number
                                                      ORDER BY datepaid) totalpaid
                                 FROM #accounts                                     
                                 WHERE datepaid >= dateadd(day, -365, convert(date, getdate()))) x
                    WHERE totalpaid >= 10000) y
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

Make sure to `PARTITION BY number` not by `number, datepaid` like you did. That effectively leaves each row as it is. (And then you also need to only `ORDER BY datepaid`. The `number` is superfluous (it's equal everywhere in the group). But it wouldn't produce a wrong result including it.).

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit however it still is not adding correctly.  For example, I have an account with 4 payments made.  The first 3 were for $369 and the last was for $16,666.  the query is just grabbing the last payment and not adding the first 3 to it.

Comment: @Greg: Sorry, mixed up the sort orders. Sort by `datepaid ASC` or `datepaid` (nothing) in both `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: Still no good.  Thanks for giving it a shot though, I do appreciate it.

Comment: @Greg: Hmm... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15598/3 looks good to me. Or I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, we filter the payments according to the date and calculate the running balance of the payments for each account.

Second, we filter the running balances greater or equal than 10000 and calculate the row number of the remaining payments for each account.

And finally, we take the first payment for each each.

```
;WITH
[RunningBalance]
AS
(
    SELECT
         [Number]
        ,[DatePaid]
        ,[TotalPaid]
        ,[RunningBalance] = SUM([TotalPaid]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Number] ORDER BY [DatePaid] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    FROM #Accounts
    WHERE ([DatePaid] >= DATEADD(DAY, -365, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))
),
[PaymentOverTotal]
AS
(
    SELECT
         [Number]
        ,[DatePaid]
        ,[TotalPaid]
        ,[RunningBalance]
        ,[RN] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Number] ORDER BY [DatePaid])
    FROM [RunningBalance]
    WHERE [RunningBalance] >= 10000
)
SELECT
     [Number]
    ,[DatePaid]
    ,[TotalPaid]
    ,[RunningBalance]
FROM [PaymentOverTotal]
WHERE ([RN] = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this a shot.  Unfortunately this returned no results at all.  I ended up breaking out the query into several smaller queries to achieve my end result.  Wasn't my first choice, but it works.

Comment: I was using the table #PaymentDate instead of #Accounts. Let's change that.

Comment: In case you want all the payments remove the condition RN = 1.

Comment: This still does not work properly.  No worries though, I went a different way with it.  Thanks again for giving it a shot.